# Read a particular status keyword from Cisco output in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, cisco-ios

I am trying to run a show command on a cisco router to find out the down interfaces.

I would like to print only the Ethernet Interface name(for eg:Eth1/3) for those are having the Status as **down** in the command output in a JSON fromat.

**Cisco output(input.json)**

```
[
    [
        [
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
            "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Eth1/20         --      eth  routed down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
            "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Eth1/21         --      eth  routed down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
            "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Eth1/22         --      eth  routed down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
            "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Eth1/23         --      eth  routed down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Playbook**

```
    - name: Set global device name
      set_fact:
        global_device_name: "{{ device_name }}"
  

    - name: Execute command on interfaces
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        commands:
          -  "show interface {{ item }} brief"
      loop: "{{ hostvars[global_device_name]['ports'] }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ global_device_name }}"
      register: command_output
      changed_when: false
    
    - name: Create a list of interface details
      set_fact:
        interface_list: "{{ interface_list|default([]) + [item.stdout_lines] }}"
      loop: "{{ command_output.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      
    - name: Save output to JSON file
      copy:
        content: "{{ interface_list  | to_nice_json}}"
        dest: output.json
    
    - name: Firewall Rule Create/Update variable
      set_fact: 
        command_output: "{{ lookup('file', 'output.json') }}"  
    
    - name: Firewall Rule Create/Update variable
      set_fact:   
        interface_details: "{{ command_output|map('flatten')}}"
    
    - name: Format output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ interface_details  }}"
```

Here the **interface_details** is the Cisco output

With the above playbook i am getting an empty array.

Comment: Have you confirmed using the `state: gathered` of the [purposed module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_interfaces_module.html)? This way you'd get an easy to parse JSON as return.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I am using ios_commands module to get a show output. So is it possible to use state: gathered along with that? Your suggestion would be helpful. Updating some more info about the playbook

Answer (score 1):

Given the file *command_output.yml* for testing

```yaml
shell> cat command_output.yml
[
  [
    [
      "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
      "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
      "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Eth1/1          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
      "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
      "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Eth1/2          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
       "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port",
      "Interface                                                                    Ch #",
      "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "Eth1/3          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Read the file and flatten the lists

```yaml
  command_output: "{{ lookup('file', 'command_output.yml') }}"
  interface_details: "{{ command_output|map('flatten') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  interface_details:
  - - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port
    - 'Interface                                                                    Ch #'
    - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Eth1/1          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --
  - - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port
    - 'Interface                                                                    Ch #'
    - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Eth1/2          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --
  - - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Ethernet        VLAN    Type Mode   Status  Reason                 Speed     Port
    - 'Interface                                                                    Ch #'
    - '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    - Eth1/3          1       eth  trunk  down    XCVR not inserted        auto(D) --
```

Get the dictionary *interface_status*

```yaml
  interface_status: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in interface_details %}
    {% set val=i.4|split() %}
    {{ val.0 }}: {{ val.4 }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  interface_status:
    Eth1/1: down
    Eth1/2: down
    Eth1/3: down
```

---

Optionally, the declarations below give the same result

```yaml
  interface_values: "{{ interface_details|
                        map(attribute='4')|
                        map('split') }}"
  interface_status: "{{ dict(interface_values|map(attribute='0')|
                             zip(interface_values|map(attribute='4'))) }}"
```

---

and select(filter) the the interfaces

```yaml
  interface_filtered: "{{ interface_status|dict2items|
                          selectattr('value', 'eq','down')|
                          map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  interface_filtered:
  - Eth1/1
  - Eth1/2
  - Eth1/3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    command_output: "{{ lookup('file', 'command_output.yml') }}"
    interface_details: "{{ command_output|map('flatten') }}"

    interface_status: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in interface_details %}
      {% set val=i.4|split() %}
      {{ val.0 }}: {{ val.4 }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
    interface_values: "{{ interface_details|
                          map(attribute='4')|
                          map('split') }}"
    interface_statu2: "{{ dict(interface_values|map(attribute='0')|
                               zip(interface_values|map(attribute='4'))) }}"
    interface_filtered: "{{ interface_status|dict2items|
                            selectattr('value', 'eq','down')|
                            map(attribute='key') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: interface_details
    - debug:
        var: interface_status
    - debug:
        var: interface_statu2
    - debug:
        var: interface_filtered
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am facing some difficulty in doing the flatten of that list. i am using this  "{{ interface_details | flatten  | to_nice_yaml}}" to do the flatten, but it is not proper as you have mentioned in your solution above. Could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: You have to *map* the filter *flatter* `command_output | map('flatten')`. I fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Not sure what mistake i am doing. The provided input is in JSON format and i think you have considered that as a yml file. I have even tried by saving the input file as yml and still not getting the expected output as shown in your example. Let me paste the complete playbook here to get an overview.

Comment: JSON is a subset of YAML. In other words, JSON is valid YAML.